# how can I put particular action as I select any row of UITableViewController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have an table and some item on it, now I want to call a method as I select particular row and like some sort of alert msg with index which in selected,

Any Solution????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is implement this method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

For more details, you can just do a search in your Xcode's developer documentation.

Comment: how can I see that which index is selected, like I want to print 0 at 0 row, 1 at 1 row etc etc...